# Why is $\sqrt{5}$ an element of every field of order $p^{2 e}$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

This was claimed in an answer to another question I asked but it's unclear to me why it's true.  I'd also be happy with a reference that explains it.  Thanks!

Comment: A much better way to phrase your question is «why is $5$ a square of every field of order $p^{2e}$?»

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see that $x^2-5$ has a root in every field of order $p^2$. If it's irreducible over the field $F$ with $p$ elements, then it has a root in the field $F[x]/(x^2-5)$ that has $p^2$ elements. Since, up to isomorphism, there is only one field of $p^2$ elements, we're done.

If $F$ is a field with $p^{2e}$ elements, then it has a subfield with $p^2$ elements, because $2$ divides $2e$.

Comment: Ah, yes!  I suppose that the same is also true for all elements of $F_p$.  For some reason, I was thinking it had something to do with 5 in particular.

Comment: @Qudit Yes: any element of degree $2$ over $F_p$ lives in $F_{p^2}$.